# combobox1_keydown errors when adding duplicate sheet names

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

In VBA I have a combobox code that will add a new formatted sheet. My problem is it errors when I entered an existing name of sheet. I need a code that shows a msgbox "sheet name already used" if a user entered a existing name of sheet.

Here is my code..

```
Private Sub combobox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As_ MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Dim wrksht1 As Worksheet, a As String
        a = ComboBox1.Value
        Set wrksht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FORMAT")
        Sheets.ADD after:= Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = a
        wrksht1.Cells.Copy

        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(a).Cells
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a helper function:

```
Function IsSheetAlreadyThere(shtName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    IsSheetAlreadyThere = Not Sheets(shtName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

and exploit it in your sub:

```
Private Sub combobox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Dim a As String
        a = ComboBox1.Value
        If IsSheetAlreadyThere(a) Then
            MsgBox a & "is the name of an already existing sheet"
        Else
            Dim wrksht1 As Worksheet
            Set wrksht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FORMAT")
            Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = a
            wrksht1.Cells.Copy
            With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(a).Cells
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a compile error at Msgbox,  expected: end of statement